# how to set google chrome as the default browser for ssrs?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I Installed SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition with Reporting Services.

When i open report configuration manager and try to connect Web Service URL or Report Manager URL,  i found the following error:

> "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click
>   continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to
>   continue"

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
...
When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

but if i set Internet Explorer as my default browser it will work well.
i don't know why i receive this error and is that depended on the version of SQL or Windows?

Comment: What are you actually asking? How to use Chrome with SSRS or why you are seeing the Unhandled exception?